# Is it possible in Java to initialise a final data member based on constructor call?

Tags: java, constructor

Is it possible to make a modification as specified in the class below, and initialize a **member** for existing callers to some default value, say `null`?

Member is required to be **private final** as persistence requirement.

```
// initial version of the class
public class A {
    A() {
        // do some work here
    }
}

// the following modification required adding additional constructor to the class with **member** data member.
public class A {
    private final String member;

    A(String member) {
        this();
        this.member = member;   
    }

    A() {
        // initilize member to null if a client called this constructor
        // do some work here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can initialize any final variable not initialized at the time of declaration in the constructor ONLY once. If you try to do it again in the same constructor or in the setter method, it will throw compiler error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why can't you just have:

```
public class A {
    private final String member;

    A(String member) {
        this.member = member;   
    }

    A() {
        this(null);
    }
}
```

This is the usual pattern for constructor chaining; have the *less-specific* versions call the *more-specific* versions, supplying default parameters as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! Why haven't I thought about it!? :)) I actually tried constructor chaining but the other way around :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes!

```
public class A {
    private final String member;

    A(String member) {
        this.member = member;
        // do some work here instead   
    }

    A() {
        this(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is usually employed in Enums.